# Android game force stop in emulator at run time

Tags: java, android, apk, logcat

i created android game apk is successfully installed on it but it not run well it give a pup up in which say force close the application:

**my logcat is as follows:**

```
07-17 01:02:25.780: D/AndroidRuntime(583): Shutting down VM
07-17 01:02:25.780: W/dalvikvm(583): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
07-17 01:02:25.811: E/AndroidRuntime(583): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-17 01:02:25.811: E/AndroidRuntime(583): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.jamescho.androidgame/com.jamescho.androidgame.SampleGame}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jamescho.androidgame.SampleGame in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.jamescho.androidgame-2.apk]
07-17 01:02:25.811: E/AndroidRuntime(583):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1544)
07-17 01:02:25.811: E/AndroidRuntime(583):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1638)
07-17 01:02:25.811: E/AndroidRuntime(583):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
07-17 01:02:25.811: E/AndroidRuntime(583):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:928)
07-17 01:02:25.811: E/AndroidRuntime(583):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-17 01:02:25.811: E/AndroidRuntime(583):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-17 01:02:25.811: E/AndroidRuntime(583):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3647)
07-17 01:02:25.811: E/AndroidRuntime(583):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-17 01:02:25.811: E/AndroidRuntime(583):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-17 01:02:25.811: E/AndroidRuntime(583):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
07-17 01:02:25.811: E/AndroidRuntime(583):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
07-17 01:02:25.811: E/AndroidRuntime(583):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-17 01:02:25.811: E/AndroidRuntime(583): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jamescho.androidgame.SampleGame in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.jamescho.androidgame-2.apk]
07-17 01:02:25.811: E/AndroidRuntime(583):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
07-17 01:02:25.811: E/AndroidRuntime(583):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
07-17 01:02:25.811: E/AndroidRuntime(583):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
07-17 01:02:25.811: E/AndroidRuntime(583):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
07-17 01:02:25.811: E/AndroidRuntime(583):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1536)
07-17 01:02:25.811: E/AndroidRuntime(583):  ... 11 more
```

Mainfest file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.jamescho.androidgame"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
       android:label="RobotGame" >
        <activity
           android:name=".SampleGame"
           android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"
           android:label="RobotGame"
           android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

please help me out it show the same problem

thanks for the reply but it not work....

Answer (score 0):

**goto**

**Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path ->  Order & Export** and **ensure Android Private Libraries are checked** for your project and for all **other library projects** you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Does your launcher Activity in your AndroidManifest really exists?

You have probably renamed this class or its package.

Comment: My Manifest file is such as i aslo rename the package ,what will i do now

Comment: You can try a clean on your project.